# How to find how many items are in the same position in two lists?python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to be able to check if any items in one list are also in another list but in the same position. I have seen others but they return true or false. I need to know how many are in the same position.

Comment: Hey, you know that StackOverflow exists to help developers, not your personal coding army? Try something yourself first, and when you get stuck, ask for help on how to proceed from there.

Comment: @A.wilson He means to show what you have tried

Comment: Exactly, your question shows no *evidence* of prior effort, and that is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So compare them directly!

This of course is assuming both lists are the same length:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
matches = 0

for index in range(len(a)):
    if a[index] == b[index]:
        matches += 1
print mat
```

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/Jo62/8)

Answer (score -1):

```
overlap = set(enumerate(listA)).intersection(set(enumerate(listB))
print(len(overlap))
```

`enumerate` pairs up elements with their index, so you can check how many common element/ index pairs exist between the two lists.

One advantage of this approach (as opposed to iterating through either list yourself) is that it automatically takes care of the case where the lists have different lengths.

[demo](https://repl.it/Jsk1)